# Numpy calculation, looking for pretty code

Tags: python, numpy

```py
tmp = []
if len(x.shape) == 1:
    output = np.array([max(0, z) for z in x])
else:
    for i in x:
        tmp.append([max(0, z) for z in i])
        output = np.array(tmp)
```

ive got this , it works but still i dont like the way its written,  looking for more "pythonic" code. Many thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Can you use `np.maximum(0,x)`?

Comment: Thx, i think the best way )